# regex match exclude specific characters in otherwise similar strings

Tags: regex

I have five strings, and I'd like to only match anything that looks like `Hello world!` without `-` in it.
Example

```
Hello world!
Hello-world!
Hi world!
Hello~world!
Hello?world!
```

regex pattern which excludes `-` is `^((?!-).)*$`, but it picks up `Hi world`.

Desired output

```
Hello world!
Hello~world!
Hello?world!
```

Comment: Try: `\bHello(?!-)\Wworld!`

Comment: You can use `(?i)^hello(?:_|[^\w-])world!$`, see [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VGCSMp/1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```php
^Hello(?:[^\w-]|_)world!$
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/j8zzit/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```php
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Hello                    'Hello'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^\w-]                   any character except: word characters (a-
                             z, A-Z, 0-9, _), '-'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    _                        '_'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  world!                   'world!'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a negated character class:

```
/^Hello\b[^-]\bworld!$/
```

The word boundaries avoid a match on strings like `Helloxworld!`

Comment: Good use of `\b` here ++

Comment: However, the word boundary does not allow an underscore here, `Hello_world!` won't get matched.

Comment: Correct, however the question is not specific enough to cover that. An alternative would be to filter in with a character class: `/^Hello[\s~?_]world!$/`. Which one to use depends on needs.